# Maven dependency not found by installer but it's in local repo

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, jfreechart

I've added the next dependency to my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
    <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.19</version>
</dependency>
```

I can run "mvn clean install" and it installs the dependency under my local repository. However when I try to install my application I get the following error:

Caused by: org.apache.felix.resolver.reason.ReasonException: Unable to resolve org.foo.app/1.0.0.SNAPSHOT: missing requirement [org.foo.app/1.0.0.SNAPSHOT] osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(osgi.wiring.package=**org.jfree.chart**)"

It's clearly a problem with the dependencies. I've tried installing the jar with "mvn install:install-file" and with the artifactId "chart" instead of "jfreechart", but it's the same.

I've also tried in the maven-bundle-plugin adding this instruction:

```
<Import-Package>!org.jfree.chart, org.jfree.jfreechart</Import-Package>
```

Doing this changes the error from osgi.wiring.package=**org.jfree.chart** to:
osgi.wiring.package=**org.jfree.jfreechart**

Any clue on how to fix this?

Comment: Maybe you are behing a proxy?

Answer (score 0):

You are not providing all the needed information to understand the question.
Any how, the error doesn't seem to be related to the dependency you mentioned in the question.
As the error states: Unable to resolve org.foo.app/1.0.0.SNAPSHOT
I guess you should figure out what is that and if your application depends on it.